# How to stop GIF at specific Frames in winfoms

Tags: c#, winforms, gif

basically my question is how to stop GIF at specific frame.

i have a picture box that is already set its image with GIF and i created a 2 events `Enter` and `Leave`

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.LOGODEFAULT1;
    }
    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.LOGOLEAVE1;
    }
```

what i want is to stop the GIF at last frame(all gif's consist of 7 frames) 
i tried the ImageAnimator and ImageStop

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageAnimator.Animate(pictureBox1.Image, OnFrameChanged1);
    }
    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(pictureBox1.Image, OnFrameChanged2); 
    }
    private void OnFrameChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.LOGODENTER;
    }
    private void OnFrameChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.LOGOLEAVE1;
    }
```

Comment: What about to create all the 7 frames and animate then on your own?

Comment: i think that will result a long code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [Image.SelectActiveFrame Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.selectactiveframe.aspx).